# How to use zsh-theme file with pure Z shell on WSL

Tags: zsh, theme, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL (Legacy (Default) which actually is Ubuntu 16.04) and I use Z shell (with no framework or plugin manager) as my shell in the terminal. My current theme is [Geometry](https://github.com/geometry-zsh/geometry) which contains a `.zsh` file alongside with its `.zsh-theme`. I use it like this in my `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
# Geometry Theme
# from https://github.com/geometry-zsh/geometry
if [[ ! -a $HOME/.zsh-plugins/geometry/geometry.zsh ]] then
    git clone https://github.com/geometry-zsh/geometry $HOME/.zsh-plugins/geometry
fi

source ~/.zsh-plugins/geometry/geometry.zsh
```

I'm using it for a while and I want to change it. New themes I selected to try (e.g. [iGeek](https://github.com/Saleh7/igeek-zsh-theme), [asciigit](https://github.com/cemsbr/asciigit), etc.), unlike my current theme, only have a `.zsh-theme` file. I followed instructions on [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346616/interactively-switching-zsh-themes-while-running-powerline), but for every theme I tried, I face this error:

```
/path/to/zsh/theme.zsh-theme:8: parse error near `\n'
```

For example, I put the first 10 lines of iGeek:

```
# igeek zsh-theme

# System load
g_load=`top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk 5 '{printf "☉ System load : %.1f%", 100-$1 }'`

# Memory Usage
g_memory=`free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "☉ Memory Usage: %.2f%", $3*100/$2 }'`

# Disk Usage
g_disk=`df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "☉ Disk Usage: %.1f%", $5}'`
```

and asciigit:

```
setopt prompt_subst

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[yellow]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_EQUAL_REMOTE=''
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_BEHIND_REMOTE='<'
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_AHEAD_REMOTE='>'
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIVERGED_REMOTE="%{$fg[red]%}<>%{%F{14}%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_UNTRACKED='%%'
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_ADDED='+'
```

Worth noting that I've downloaded `.zsh-theme` files using `curl` command from WSL's terminal and did no change to them. For example:

```
curl https://github.com/cemsbr/asciigit/blob/master/asciigit.zsh-theme --create-dirs -o ~/.zsh-plugins/asciigit/asciigit.zsh-theme
```

The odd thing is, as far as I tried, it only errors on line 8 though there are different things on line 8 in different files.

Is there any way to use such themes without the need to use a plugin manager?

Comment: Welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https:unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question. Could you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/534551/edit) your post to include more information. What does `/path/to/zsh/theme.zsh-theme` line 8 look like? A quick search into zsh errors I found that you could get this type of error if a function is not closed properly.  Line 8 is your clue.

Comment: @kemotep I've put a link to iGeek and asciigit for this purpose. In the iGeek like 8 is empty and in the asciigit it's an environment variable being assigned. I'll update the question with their code snippet.

Comment: We prefer if people put all relevant details in the post and avoid only linking to 3rd party sites or posting screenshots as the information is harder to work with and sites can change or go dark. If that were to happen your post would have a mismatch of information and be harder to work with if people were to come across it years later.

Comment: Looking further into your issue I have found discrepancies in how Windows and Linux handle files. Potentially your files are in a DOS format when they need to be Unix or vice versa. WSL 1 is very much a grey area of not quite Windows not quite Linux. So please edit your post to include the following details: 1. Is this WSL 1 or WSL 2? 2. Did you download the files from the bash shell or did you download or otherwise manipulate them from the Windows host first? 3. Have you confirmed that the file is in the correct format (DOS/Unix) that zsh needs in WSL? Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep I need your help before I update my post. I wasn't aware of the WSL 2. I searched about it and come over [this site](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-is-now-available-in-windows-insiders/). I tried `wsl --list` (gave no version info) and `wsl --list --verbose` (complained that there is no verbose option). By the way, my WSL distro is Ubuntu 16.04 which is called **Legacy (Default)** by the windows itself. Also, I've downloaded every theme I tried (including iGeek and asciigit) using curl with no furthur change to them.

Comment: You need that Windows 10 version 1903 to even install WSL 2. If you do not have 1903, then you have the first version of WSL. I suspect based on your comment that you have WSL 1. From what I have found you should be able to change themes as simply as following [this advice](https://blog.joaograssi.com/windows-subsystem-for-linux-with-oh-my-zsh-conemu/) The line ending error means that you need to make sure that all your linux files have linux file endings. Try to use dos2unix or some other program to convert them.

Comment: @kemotep What you've told me about dos2unix lead me to the true cause of this issue. The problem was that the URL I've used with the curl command downloads an HTML page and not the raw .zsh-theme file. But I didn't notice that because I never looked into the file it has downloaded. But because of your last comment, after using dos2unix and failing again to apply the theme, I looked into the file and noticed the wrong file is downloaded and after a little investigation, I found out that the URL I give to the curl is not what I should give. Sorry for being so much careless and thank you.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue thanks to the hint @kemotep gave me.

I was using the wrong link with the curl command (link of the GitHub's file viewer page). Instead, I should use the link of the raw file. For example:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cemsbr/asciigit/master/asciigit.zsh-theme --create-dirs -o ~/.zsh-plugins/asciigit/asciigit.zsh-theme
```

And then adding `source ~/.zsh-plugins/asciigit/asciigit.zsh-theme` to the `~/.zshrc` file and doing a `source ~/.zshrc` will apply the theme.